# GPS (Lat+Long+Alt) Corrected Absolute Rotation from Magnetometer+Accelerometer. How?

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have successfully computed the (device-relative earth orientation) rotation $\mathbf{R}$ from my geomagnetic vector $\mathbf{m}$ and gravity vector reading $\mathbf{g}$ as follows:

$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
\textrm{normalize}(\mathbf{m}\times\mathbf{g})^T\\ 
\textrm{normalize}(\mathbf{g}\times(\mathbf{m}\times\mathbf{g}))^T\\ 
\textrm{normalize}(\mathbf{g})^T
\end{bmatrix}$.

I also have my Latitude($\phi$), Longitude ($\lambda$), Altitude ($h$) from GPS.

I have transformed this into its absolute Cartesian form, $[x,y,z]^T$ using the equations given in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates).

But now my problem is to convert the relative rotation $\mathbf{R}$ to its absolute form $\mathbf{R}_{abs}$.

What are the equations that I have to use here?

Thanks.